# Powershell: Question regarding % (Percent sign) and how it might work in the below snippet of script

Tags: powershell

I'm working on improving my PowerShell and I have been working on over-hauling a script but I'm still pretty green so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I understand the `%` is ForEach-Object but this is a bit different.  If you could help me understand them in this snippet, it would be appreciated.

```
function Replace-StringVariables ($string, $location) {
    $string = $string.Replace("%locationID%",$location.locationID)
    $string = $string.Replace("%locationName%",$location.locationName)
    $string = $string.Replace("%locationCode%",$location.locationCode)
    $string = $string.Replace("%regionName%",$location.regionName)
    $string = $string.Replace("%regionCode%",$location.regionCode)
}
```

So, I figured out the `$strong` confusion on this, what I'm not understanding the `%'s` before AND after some of these. This is an AD project if it helps.

Comment: the percent-bounded words look like placeholders in a text object that the author wanted to replace with values from the `$Location` variable. it has nothing to do with either `ForEach-Object` or with the modulus operator. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've got it all figured out.  It's pulling information from a previous json that had been converted to raw data into this.  At least, that's how I'm understanding it.